# ¿Como recuperar o restablecer contraseña por medio de correo electrónico?

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo creado un registro de usuario el cual toda la informacion se guarda en la base de datos con Mysql, y también tengo creado un inicio de sesión para cada usuario el cual hasta el momento ingresa sin problema, lo que quiero es que cuando el usuario olvide su contraseña mande un correo para que se restablezca o se le genere una nueva, he visto que se puede restablecer pero por firebase, hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo diferente ya que tengo los datos en Mysql o si se puede recuperar mandando un correo a gmail, por lo pronto tengo el método sendEmail pero es ahí donde no he podido hacer la funcionalidad para enviar su correo del usuario cuando lo solicite.

**ForgtoPass.java**

```
public class ForgotPass extends AppCompatActivity {
  TextInputEditText correo;
  Button btnRecuperar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forgot_pass);
    
    correo = findViewById(R.id.texcorreoForgot);
    btnRecuperar =  findViewById(R.id.btnForgot);

    btnRecuperar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            validarCampo();
        }
    });

}
public boolean validarCampo(){
    boolean retorno=true;
    String email= correo.getText().toString().trim();

    if (email.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Favor de llenar el campo correo electrónico", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        correo.requestFocus();
        retorno = false;
    } else {
        if (email.isEmpty() || !Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Correo electrónico invalido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            correo.requestFocus();
            retorno = false;
        }
    }

    sendEmail(email);
    return retorno;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(ForgotPass.this,LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

public void sendEmail(String email){

    String emailAddress = email;


   }
  }
```

Comment: No puedes enviar un email propio tuyo desde el dispositivo de un usuario. El envío de emails se hace desde los servidores, no los clientes. Imagínate que cualquier app que te descargas tuviese acceso sin límites a tu email y pudiese enviar correos sin más... pues vaya gracia. Además, android no es un servidor SMTP, lo único que puede hacer es abrir la APP de gmail o cualquier otro gestor de correos, pero eso sirve para que el usuario envíe un correo él, no para que reciba uno. Para esto último, como dije, necesitas hacerlo desde tu servidor, no desde el cliente.

Comment: @Benito-B una parte si te entiendo, solo que mi duda es o el detalle que tengo yo como usuario se me olvida mi contraseña y necesito que me la restablezcan o me generen una nueva.

Answer (score 1):

Primero, debe crear una "página oculta", una página en su aplicación a la que solo se puede acceder desde un enlace directo, no desde cualquier menú. En esta página, recibe una **ID** y un **TOKEN/HASH** como parámetros, tiene dos campos para la nueva contraseña y un botón de envío (y algún texto útil o explicación para el usuario).

Para la acción de envío, si la ID existe, el token es válido y ambas contraseñas coinciden, actualiza (reemplaza) la contraseña del usuario cuya ID es la misma que la ID informada como parámetro.

Ahora su página de "cambio de contraseña" está lista.

Lo siguiente es crear el correo electrónico.
Cada vez que alguien hace clic en "Olvidé mi contraseña", genera un gran token aleatorio y lo guarda en algún lugar vinculado a la identificación de este usuario (una tabla simple con solo dos columnas sería suficiente por ahora). También deberá crear un método para enviar un correo electrónico, [consulte esta pregunta como ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884943/how-do-i-send-an-e-mail-in-java).

Deberá escribir un HTML simple para que sea el contenido del correo electrónico, dentro de él habrá un enlace a su "página de cambio de contraseña", no olvide poner en este enlace la ID y el TOKEN para este cliente como los parámetros que debe recibir su página.

¡Y hecho! Los pasos principales están ahí.

Por supuesto, puede hacerlo más seguro, por ejemplo, poniendo un tiempo de caducidad para el token, como otra columna en su tabla con una marca de tiempo de su creación, y luego calculando si ha pasado X tiempo desde su creación, recibiendo más parámetros en lugar de solo identificación y token, pero los conceptos básicos están cubiertos.